# How to get the date with Frensh formatting

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use `moment.js` in my project, what I want is to alert the date in French, I tried this:

```
alert(moment('2012-10-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'fr', true););
```

But it alerts it in English, help please.

Comment: @ScottMarcus This question is about momentjs not JS dates.

Comment: yes i'm using moment js

Comment: @MrGeek The question was not tagged with `momentjs` when I closed it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the usage of `moment()` in the code should be a clue.

Comment: Not if you don’t use momentjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like this:

```js
alert(moment('2012-10-14').format('dddd Do MMMM YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i want it in frensh like that: lundi 12 janvier 2017

Comment: @imsiimsi, *"lundi", "janvier "*, what the language is it, French? Momentjs can convert inly in English. I have updated the answer. Is it an expected result?